# How to exclude records from results when ID from A table is in PID column of B table for the same PUID

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, inner-join

How to exclude records from results when ID from A table is in PID column of B table for the same PUID[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61wcw.png)

Table A:

```
PUID      PID          SYSTEMCODE      ID

100000  701848421         A         3207479
```

Table B:

```
PUID    PID        SYSTEMCODE

100000  3207479     B

100000  6805875     B
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from tablea a 
where not exists (select 1 from tableb b where b.pid = a.id and b.puid = a.puid)
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB, even when I use not exists still I see records in the results