# How to exclude all records for PUID from the result when A.PUID = B.EUID and A.PID <> B.LID

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to exclude all records for PUID from the result when A.PUID = B.EUID and A.PID <> B.LID

[image: Tables and expected result attached here]

**Table A**

```
PUID PID PCODE                               
100        1003    RG    
200        1006    CA    
200        1007    CA    
300        1008    RG
```

**Table B**

```
EUID      LID        ECODE    
100       1003        RG    
100       1004         RG    
100        1005        RG    
200        1006         CA    
300         1009       RG
```

**Expected Result**

```
PUID          PID             ECODE    
300          1008              RG
```

**Tried with not exists, didn't work.** **screen print for tables attached**

Comment: Why isn't `200 1007 CA` also in results? It has a match in Table B on the first column, but doesn't match the second.

Comment: Your data does not match your explanation.

Comment: Perhaps we need a stack site for help with homework

Comment: You said "How to exclude all records for PUID from the result when A.PUID = B.EUID and A.PID <> B.LID". Do you really mean to exclude the records matching this condition or include? Either cases your expected result doesn't match. Please edit the question to make the inclusion/exclusion logic clear and corresponding result set.

Comment: How is this different from your two previous questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64794523/how-to-exclude-records-from-results-when-id-from-a-table-is-in-pid-column-of-b-t, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64815579/if-id-from-table-a-is-in-pid-column-of-table-b-then-i-want-to-exclude-both-r, where you did not accept any answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below - **[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9ccaf69487bbd7e04750213999b923db)**

```
select A.* from A
join
(
select A.puid
from A left join B on A.puid=B.puid and A.pid=B.pid
group by A.puid having sum(case when B.pid is null then 0 else 1 end)=0
)X on A.puid=X.puid
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at join logic for the database, if you join on a column you can take those that are the same (contains) or those that null (does not contain) there are different types of joins that can be used in combination with a where statement and in your homework assignment your mentors likes you to understand and apply them.

Open google and look at joins, or look at this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use a `left join` and window functions:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             count(b.euid) over (partition by a.puid) as num_matches
      from a left join
           b
           on a.puid = b.euid and a.pid = b.lid
     ) a
where num_matches = 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bdbbcd64b05fe95bef324a2497093de3) is a db<>fiddle.